# BroadcastReceiver is not called

Tags: android, android-intent

I have to following code to call the BroadcastReceiver:

```
 public class WorkItemAlarmManager {
    ...
        public void initAlarm(HelpMe helpMe, String delay,String period,WorkItem workItem){
            //HelpMe = Activity
helpMe.registerReceiver(new WorkItemAlarmHandler() , new IntentFilter("WORK_ITEM_ALARM"));

            Intent intent = new Intent("WORK_ITEM_ALARM");
            intent.setClass(helpMe, WorkItemAlarmManager.class);
            intent.putExtra("work_item", workItem);
            PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(helpMe, 0,intent, 0);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            //System.out.println("START"+System.currentTimeMillis());   
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, calcDelayMillis(delay));
            //System.out.println("END"+calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) helpMe.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), mAlarmSender);
        }
    ...
    }
```

and the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class WorkItemAlarmHandler extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ....
    }

}
```

But the WorkItemAlarmHandler is never called.

Update:
I tried to register the BroadcastReceiver in the manifest at first. But that didn't work:

```
<receiver
            android:name="de.helpme.alarm.WorkItemAlarmHandler"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="WorkItemAlarmHandler" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="WORK_ITEM_ALARM" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Thanks for your answers :). Now it works - but i dont yet know which one is the correct because i implemented both answers at once. If a figure out which was the right one i mark the right as answer.

**Update:** 
The cause of the problem as i see it was:

```
PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(helpMe, 0,intent, 0);
```

With this code it works fine:

```
PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(helpMe, 0, intent, 0);
```

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: did you register in manifest.xml post that code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

In WorkItemAlarmManager ;

```
public class WorkItemAlarmManager {
    ...
        public void initAlarm(HelpMe helpMe, String delay,String period,WorkItem workItem){
            Intent intent =new Intent(helpMe, WorkItemAlarmHandler.class);
            intent.setAction("WORK_ITEM_ALARM");
            intent.putExtra("work_item", workItem);
            PendingIntent mAlarmSender=
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(helpMe, 0, intent, 0);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            //System.out.println("START"+System.currentTimeMillis());   
            calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, calcDelayMillis(delay));
            //System.out.println("END"+calendar.getTimeInMillis());
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) helpMe.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), mAlarmSender);
        }
    ...
    }
```

and in WorkItemAlarmHandler:

```
public class WorkItemAlarmHandler extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("WORK_ITEM_ALARM")){
            Toast.makeText(context, "WORK_ITEM_ALARM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "repeating alarm",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses:

```
intent.setClass(helpMe, WorkItemAlarmManager.class);
```

but with the setClass(...) method you specify the class that should finally handle the intent.

Therefore you should write:

```
intent.setClass(helpMe, WorkItemAlarmHandler.class);
```

As far as I remember, if you specify the class or component manually (eg. with the setClass() method) this object has to be specified in the manifest, so make sure the receiver is mentioned there.

Comment: As far as I know you can do perfectly fine without setting a class when it's about broadcasts.